# How to split up a paragraph using words

Tags: c#, string, split, docx

My question is, how would you split this paragraph for example into two strings? Part A and Part B? I am reading it from a word document using DocX dll. Keep in mind the text may change. The full stops may not be present. But the paragraphs will always be divided by part a,b,c and so on.... Thanks!

"Part A So close no matter how far. Couldn't be much more from the heart.Forever trusting who we are.And nothing else matters.Part B Never opened myself this way.
Life is ours, we live it our way.All these words I don't just say.And nothing else matters"

Comment: I guess you could if you have a unique word to split the paragraph with and place it within the paragraph where you want it to split. Then use string.Split()

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to split your paragraph into lines, if the division is to be done on Part A, Part B etc.

```
string para = "Part A So close no matter how far. Couldn't be much more from the heart.Forever trusting who we are.And nothing else matters.Part B Never opened myself this way. Life is ours, we live it our way.All these words I don't just say.And nothing else matters";

Regex regex = new Regex("Part [A-Z] ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string[] lines = regex.Split(para).Where(s => s != String.Empty).ToArray();
```